# python3 itertools.filterfalse is very slow. What are the alternatives?

Tags: python

I want to get difference between two list of dict variables.
Those list contains 100,000 items each.
When I write below code it took more than 2 minutes. (My old laptop with Intel® Core™ i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8)

```py
added_items = list(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x in records_old, records_new))
```

This is sample record;

```
[{"email": "user-01@test.com", "login": "user-01", "type": "member"},
```

Also I need to compare both keys and values.
Can you please suggest some other faster way for this?

Comment: ah I see now, you've got essentially an `O(N^2)` lookup -- you could improve slightly by sorting both using some heuristic and then using a linear scan to compare: O(N*log(N)), or if you can produce some key for the items you could make derived maps and then intersect their keys which would be ~O(N)

Comment: [PEP 603 -- Adding a frozenmap type to collections](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0603/)

Comment: A dict `d` can be converted e.g. with `frozenset(d.items())` to an immutable, hashable object which can be put in a set. You can then create sets out of the lists and apply set operations on it.

Comment: Thanks all. I'll test those suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is *O(n^2)* time complexity and *O(1)* space.

In programming, we can often trade time for space. This approach should be *O(n)* time and *O(n)* space, with an improvement in runtime:

```
records_old_set = {frozenset(r.items()) for r in records_old}
added_items = [r for r in records_new if frozenset(r.items()) not in records_old_set]
```